# How is the secure key protected in cordova plugin encrypt source code?

Tags: cordova-plugins

When I protect my source Code with cordova plugin: "encrypt source Code"
the plugin generates a random Key to encrypt the source .

When I install the App, then files are decrypted.
The Question is: where is Key located to decrypt the source ?
Is the location secure ?